# How get multiselect values from form using Golang?

Tags: html, forms, go

I have a multiple select input in my form and I'm trying to get the selected values in my handler, but I can't, how can I get those values?

```
<form action="process" method="post">
    <select id="new_data" name="new_data class="tag-select chzn-done" multiple="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">111mm1</option>
    <option value="2">222mm2</option>
    <option value="3">012nx1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My Handler:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("new_data")) // result-> []
    fmt.Println(r.Form("new_data")) // result-> []
}
```

The form serialized data with option 1 and 2 selected from JS console:

```
   >$('#myform').serialize() 
   >"new_data=1&new_data=2"
```

Comment: Did you call [`ParseForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) on your request?

Comment: Upss that was the problem, I forgot call r.ParseForm() thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't/shouldn't use the [`Request.FormValue()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) function because that only returns 1 value. Use `Request.Form["new_data"]` which is a slice of `string`s containing all the values.
But note that if you don't call `r.FormValue()`, you have to trigger parsing the form (and populating the `Request.Form` map) by calling [`Request.ParseForm()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) explicitly.

You also have an HTML syntax error: the value of the `name` attribute is not closed, change it to:

```
<select id="new_data" name="new_data" class="tag-select chzn-done"
    multiple="" style="display: none;">
```

Here is a complete app to test that it works (error checks ommited!):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        // Form submitted
        r.ParseForm() // Required if you don't call r.FormValue()
        fmt.Println(r.Form["new_data"])
    }
    w.Write([]byte(html))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", myHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}

const html = `
<html><body>
<form action="process" method="post">
    <select id="new_data" name="new_data" class="tag-select chzn-done" multiple="" >
        <option value="1">111mm1</option>
        <option value="2">222mm2</option>
        <option value="3">012nx1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body></html>
`
```